# Calculate the volume of cloud points of a tree in python

Tags: python, volume, point-clouds, convex-hull, las

How can the volume of a point cloud (las file) be calculated with acceptable accuracy?

Visualization (CloudCompare) of the tree point cloud:
[image]

I'm trying to use convex hull, but since I have steams and foliage, it is inconsistent, because the algorithm calculates an erroneous mesh.

My code is:

```
diamond = PyntCloud.from_file(r'tree.las')
convex_hull_id = diamond.add_structure("convex_hull")
convex_hull = diamond.structures[convex_hull_id]
diamond.mesh = convex_hull.get_mesh()
diamond.to_file(r'output.obj', also_save=["mesh"])
volume = convex_hull.volume
```

Visualization of the mesh calculated by the convex hull algorithm:
[image]

Which solution can I implement in order to calculate the volume in a proper way?

Does a 'concave hull' algorithm exist? I guess it would work better.

Comment: There was quite exactly the same question asked just a few days ago. I suggest looking for it then contacting the author of that question; they might we working on a similar project as you

Comment: Well, for some reason I can't find the question again.

Comment: I can't find it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can voxelize your tree(or your point cloud) and calculate the volume of voxels that contain points. If you keep voxel resolution small, then it would give you a decent estimate. Better than convex hull at least.

You can think of it as meshing methods with voxelization. Then calculating the volume of that mesh.